# Socket Send Timeout - Is it safe to change?

Tags: python, windows, vb.net, sockets, connection-timeout

**Short Question**
Are there any dangers or gotchas to shortening [default timeout values](https://serverfault.com/questions/193160/which-is-the-default-tcp-connect-timeout-in-windows) from the 72 seconds to as short as 5 seconds?

**Background**
I have a client application in VB.NET and server in Python, both of which run on Windows 7 and monitor the active connections / shut themselves down when a broken socket is detected.  All of the logic works will when either client or server is shutdown.  The trouble comes into play if the physical network cable is removed from the PC.  After this event it takes the full 72 seconds before my socket.send() times out and exits.  Since the client side is a UI, you can imagine how irritating it would be waiting over a minute before realizing that the connection is dead.

**EDIT**
1) The client UI is not *blocked* during the timeout event.  The failure mode is the connection indication shows "Connected" for the 72 seconds even though no messages are being sent.

2) I am sending a heartbeat message from both the client and the server once a second.  With these message rates, I see a connection failure within 5 seconds if I **close** either of the applications.  This timing goes out the window when I **unplug the network cable**.  This is why I am at a loss right now...

Comment: You should never make the UI wait for a network operation.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Completely agree.  Check out my edit, I did not make it clear in my original question.

Comment: Just a quick note that if you were actually to attempt to send data, the detection should happen much sooner. I doubt having a heartbeat is the way you want to go but this sounds similar to PHP's inability to know if a client has disconnected if it (php) is not sending data.

Comment: @Basic I am actually sending heartbeats from both sides, however I was relying on the `Send()` method to flag the connection as dead.  So I too was expecting unplugging the network cable to be detected much sooner.

Comment: That surprises me. I'm interested to see if you get any good answers as I'd like to know myself now.

Comment: @AdamLewis: If you need to detect connection loss more quickly, you *must* send data more often. Otherwise, there's no way to know whether the connection is still alive.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am sending a heatbeat once a second from both sides.  Check out my edit for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a heartbeat once a second, and have not received a heartbeat for, say, five seconds, you should consider the connection lost. This is basically just a UI issue -- you have the information, you're just not reporting it.

Comment: As my comments to Basic stated, when this was written I was using the `Send()` timeout to flag the connection as down.  I have since replaced this logic to drop if a message isn't received.  However this still does not explain why the `Send()` doesn't timeout when the cable is removed.

Comment: It does timeout, it just takes quite some time to do so. It is a design feature of the TCP protocol that brief interruptions in connectivity do not break connections.

Comment: The thing I'm not understanding is even after I set the send timeout to say 5 seconds, it still takes the full 72 seconds before it 'times out' after a cable is removed.

Comment: Right, because the send succeeds immediately, having sent the data (likely by putting it in the TCP stack's send queue). The connection times out only much later when the TCP stack realizes the sent data has not been acknowledged. The "send" operation only involves arranging to have the data sent. The actual sending of the data can take place later. The actual operation of the TCP connection's network protocol engine is asynchronous to the application commanding the stack to do things. The send timeout handles things like send queue full backpressure, not end-to-end acknowledgement.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I hadn't really thought of the timeout actually happening lower in the stack.  It seems this kinda downplays the usefulness in being able to set the send timeout at the socket level.

Comment: @AdamLewis: It's useful for controlling how long you wait for space to be available in the send buffer. But it does *not* deal with connection timeouts, only send timeouts. If you need application-level acknowledgements and timeouts, you have to code them. The TCP layer is designed to be robust in the face of network disruptions, not detect them by failing quickly.